# Powercli Import-VApp with RunAsync does not finish in order?

Tags: powershell, powercli

I have a simple task to use PowerCLI to deploy three VMs from the same OVA and do it asynchronously.  In order to do that, I am using the -RunAsync option in my script.

```
$task1 = Import-VApp –Source $ovapath –OvfConfiguration $ovaconfig –Name "$ovafile-1" –VMHost $myhost –Datastore $datastore –DiskStorageFormat Thin -Runasync
```

My script has $task2 and $task3 as well but not shown here for brevity as they are nearly identical.

It works, but the odd behavior I see is that VM#2 always seems to finish first, and then about 30 seconds later, VM1 and VM3 seem to finish almost at the same time.  Is there a way to influence the order in which an OVA gets deployed or the order it finishes?  I tried putting a 'sleep 2' after each $task just to have a small gap between the deploying of the VMs to try and eliminate a possible race condition.  Same result.  VM2 always wins and VM1 and 3 finish together.

For clarity, I am running PowerCLI 6.5R1 and vCenter 6.0 latest patch.

Comment: `-RunAsync` basically means 'Run it in parallel and disregard order of invocation`. It is faster though. In your case, Task1 moves to task 2 as soon as it is executed and does not wait for it to finish before executing tas2.  But if you want it in order, run it synchronously. (Meaning don't use the -RunAsync switch). Will do one computer at a time. takes way longer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I agree running synchronous is way too long.  What I find odd is that I am kicking off the VMs from the same OVA file, kicking off task#1, waiting 2 seconds before kicking off task#2 based on the same OVA file.  That 2 second break ought to make sure VM1 wins, but it never does.  This maybe an artifact in how vCenter does things in the background.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't sound like a PowerShell issue.